Using BreakLoopOp in Qiskit
While looking at the Qiskit documentation, I saw that using control flow was also a loop breaking process, so I added a condition with the BreakLoopOp class and tried to perform the operations inside the loop. But from the results I couldn't quite figure out how this worked.
It takes measurements automatically even if I don't take measurements.
Can you explain in which areas this class is used and how exactly it works?
I'm posting the code I ran below.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, transpile
from qiskit.circuit.controlflow import BreakLoopOp
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import SamplerV2


backend_aer = AerSimulator()
sampler = SamplerV2(mode=backend_aer)


qreg_1 = QuantumRegister(2,"qreg_1")
creg_1 = ClassicalRegister(2,"creg_1")
qc_1 = QuantumCircuit(qreg_1,creg_1)


loop_sayisi = 5


loop_body_1 = QuantumCircuit(qreg_1,creg_1)
loop_body_1.h(1)
loop_body_1.x(0)




condition_circuit_1 = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
#condition_circuit_1.measure(1,1)
break_op = BreakLoopOp(num_qubits=2,num_clbits=2)


loop_body_1.append(condition_circuit_1,qreg_1,creg_1)
loop_body_1.append(break_op,qreg_1,creg_1) 

for_loop_1 = ForLoopOp(range(loop_sayisi),None,loop_body_1, label='For Loop')
qc_1.append(for_loop_1,qreg_1,creg_1)



qc_1_transpile = transpile(qc_1,backend=backend_aer)
job_sampler = sampler.run([(qc_1_transpile,None,1000)])

result_sampler = job_sampler.result()
count_sampler = result_sampler[0].data.creg_1.get_counts()
count_sampler = {k[::-1] : v for k,v in count_sampler.items()}
print(count_sampler)

qc_1.draw(output="mpl",style = "iqp-dark",initial_state=True)

Output :
{'00': 1000}

